# Good books for undergraduates to understand Milankovitch cycles

Tags: astrophysics, resource-recommendations, solar-system, geophysics, climate-science

Forgive me for wierd expression becaus English is not my native tongue. I want some suggestion for books about the math and physics about how [Milankovitch cycles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milankovitch_cycles) were calculated. i.e. How eccentricity, tilt, precession cycles are determined. Maybe textbook on celestial mechanics will help but I do not know which book I should start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the hard physics of it, I always reference [Introduction to Celestial Mechanics by Richard Fitzpatrick](https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/celestial/Celestial/Celestial.html) for things like that. For example, it calculates the perihelion precession of Mercury due to the other planets. In particular, [the introduction](https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/celestial/Celestial/node1.html) lists a number of books which surely cover the Milankovitch cycles.

Alternatively, if you just want to determine the cycles yourself, it would be much much easier to just numerically solve Newton's equations $\ddot{x}_i=\sum_j \frac{G m_i}{x_{ij}^3} \vec{x}_{ij}$ and do a Fourier transform :)